# How to make a form always top of taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms

I want create a form in C# that always be on top of taskbar and other programs.
I try with Topmost but when I click on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or start button on keyboard, taskbar is top of my form.

Comment: Preventing the user from using his taskbar and the windows of other apps is excessively hostile.  Windows will not put up with that.  The only way to do it is go whole-hog, you must create a borderless window that's maximized.

Comment: Relevant: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx

Comment: @MarkJansen Best text ever, was about to post that :)

Answer (score 1):

Ugly approach: use Timer.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopMost = true;
}
```

Better not to do so.

Comment: @neli - Form is always on top of taskbar.

Comment: if i clicked on Alt + Tab  or start button,taskbar is top of my form.your solution doesnt work

Comment: @neli - The taskbar is usually located below the desktop. What appears when you press Alt + Tab is not the taskbar.

Comment: but taskbar comming up.i want my form always be top of other programming even startmenu

Comment: @neli - Briefly - it's impossible. Good luck!